# Password control is not being sent to server

Tags: c#, webforms

I am trying to make a user register for my project and I want to take user's password with input(password). I used textboxes for name and surname and I can save them to database but I can't get user's input which has entered in input(password). Here is my code which I am using to save users in database.

```
TermProjectEntities entity = new TermProjectEntities();

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Customer cust = new Customer
    {
        Name = txtName.Text,
        Surname = txtSurname.Text,
        Email = txtEmail.Text,
    };
 }
```

I can take textboxes variables with "textboxe's id.Text" but it's not working for input(password). Thanks for the help and sorry if it's an easy question and took your time.

Here is the HTML:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        Name:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox><br /> 

        Surname:
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtSurname" runat="server"></asp:TextBox><br />

        Password:
        <input id="txtPassword" type="password" /><br />

        E-Mail:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtEmail" runat="server"></asp:TextBox><br />

        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Register" OnClick="Button1_Click" /> <br /> 
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Is this an ASP.NET WebForms website, or a Windows Forms application?

Comment: @RichardEverett asp.net wf. (xxx.Text)

Comment: You probably set something in pageLoad without checking IsPostBack

Comment: it's an asp.net web forms website.Sorry for forgetting to write

Comment: Show us your HTML mark-up (have got `runat="Server"` for example) and what do you mean by "Not working"... Very general term. You get NULL, you can't find the control, you are seeing some other data?!

Comment: <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
       Name:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;<asp:TextBox ID="txtName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox><br />
       Surname: <asp:TextBox ID="txtSurname" runat="server"></asp:TextBox><br />
       Password:<input id="txtPassword" type="password" /><br />
        E-Mail:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtEmail" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <br />
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Register" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
        <br />
    </div>
    </form>

Comment: there isn't an error.It's not responsing to input(password)'s id like textboxes's ids

Comment: @user3173750 - I have edited your question to put the HTML in the question itself and also spotted the issue. I have answered, see below and please try.

Answer (score 0):

I have copied your HTML from your comment onto the question to make it easier for people to answer. But while I was there I saw the problem is your password is not set to run on the server (therefore will not be sent back when you click the button).

So you currently have this:

```
<input id="txtPassword" type="password" /><br />
```

But it should be this:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtPassword" runat="server" TextMode="Password"></asp:TextBox><br />
```

So, there are two main points:

1. Use `asp:TextBox` and not `input` to leverage ASP .NET Framework
2. Ensure every control you want to use contains `runat="server"`

This is because ASP .NET is **Server-Side** so you need to get your controls back to the server before they can be accessed and this is what the `runat="server"` attribute achieves.

You can then use attributes like `TextMode="Password"` to control how items are shown/act.